# Equivalent WFF Schemas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to show how to define $\neg\phi$, $\phi\lor\psi$ and $\phi\land\psi$ using only two connectives: $\{\rightarrow, \bot\}$ where $\bot$ is an arbitrary definition.

Does anyone have advice about how to do these definitions, or tips or trips, or how to think about equivalencies that hold between formulas that involve metavariables?

Here is an example of what I have:
Here is how to symbolize $\neg\phi$ using only $\rightarrow$ and/or $\bot:$ $\phi\rightarrow\phi.$ Notice that $\neg\phi$ is semantically equivalent to $\neg(\phi\land\phi),$ which itself is semantically equivalent to $\phi\rightarrow (\phi\land\neg\phi).$ I can symbolize the latter, though, like this: $\phi\rightarrow\bot.$ So, I can symbolize $\neg\phi$ as $\phi\rightarrow\bot.$

Comment: Not clear; $\bot$ is the symbol for [FALSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)#False.2C_negation_and_contradiction), i.e. a propositional constant that is always false. Thus, $\lnot \phi$ can correctly be defined as $\phi \to \bot$ (check with truth table).

Comment: The others are straightforward: $\phi \lor \psi$ is $\lnot \phi \to \psi$. Thus, it is enough to replace $\lnot$ with the previous definition.

Comment: So even though I am using metavariables I can substitute equivalences whenever I want?

Comment: @Rusty Yes, all equivalences still hold true when using meta-variables.